# Unable to set ID column in case of left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have some record as under for **tblFiltered**

```
ID  RowID   Position    Data
1   1        a1          R
1   1        b1          N
1   1        e1          K
1   1        g1          N
1   1        h1          R
1   2        b2          T
1   2        c2          B
1   2        d2          Y
1   2        f2          F
```

And the table **tblComplete** has the below data

```
RowID   Position    Data
1         a1        NULL
1         b1        NULL
1         c1        NULL
1         d1        NULL
1         e1        NULL
1         f1        NULL
1         g1        NULL
1         h1        NULL
2         a2        NULL
2         b2        NULL
2         c2        NULL
2         d2        NULL
2         e2        NULL
2         f2        NULL
2         g2        NULL
2         h2        NULL
```

The desired output is

```
ID  RowID   Position  CompleteData
1   1         a1           R
1   1         b1           N
1   1         c1           NULL
1   1         d1           NULL
1   1         e1           K
1   1         f1           NULL
1   1         g1           N
1   1         h1           R
1   2         a2           NULL
1   2         b2           T
1   2         c2           B
1   2         d2           Y
1   2         e2           NULL
1   2         f2           F
1   2         g2           NULL
1   2         h2           NULL
```

That means the records that are not in tblFiltered will be taken from tblCompelete and it will be filled.
e.g. c1, d1 and f1 are not in tblFiltered and henceforth are taken from tblCompelte and being added to the resultant output.

I have written the query

```
select t.ID,c.RowID,c.Position,
 CompleteData = case when t.Data IS null then null else t.data end
from @CompleteData c
left join @tblFiltered t 
on c.Position = t.Position
```

whose output is

```
ID    RowID Position    CompleteData
1       1       a1               R
1       1       b1               N
NULL    1       c1               NULL
NULL    1       d1               NULL
1       1       e1               K
NULL    1       f1               NULL
1       1       g1               N
1       1       h1               R
NULL    2       a2               NULL
1       2       b2               T
1       2       c2               B
1       2       d2               Y
NULL    2       e2               NULL
1       2       f2               F
NULL    2       g2               NULL
NULL    2       h2               NULL
```

As can be seen, *I am unable to set the ID*. Also, if the ID's become > 1 in tblFiltered, then how will I keep track of that?

DDL are

```
Declare @tblFiltered table(ID int,RowID int,Position varchar(10),Data varchar(10))     
Insert into @tblFiltered     
Select 1,1,'a1','R' union all     
Select 1,1,'b1','N' union all     
Select 1,1,'e1','K' union all     
Select 1,1,'g1','N' union all     
Select 1,1,'h1','R' union all     
Select 1,2,'b2','T' union all     
Select 1,2,'c2','B' union all     
Select 1,2,'d2','Y'  union all   
Select 1,2,'f2','F'

Declare @CompleteData table (RowID int,Position varchar(10),Data varchar(10))
Insert into @CompleteData
select  1, 'a1', Null Union All
select  1, 'b1', Null Union All
select  1, 'c1', Null Union All
select  1, 'd1', Null Union All
select  1, 'e1', Null Union All
select  1, 'f1', Null Union All
select  1, 'g1', Null Union All
select  1, 'h1', Null Union All
select  2, 'a2', Null Union All
select  2, 'b2', Null Union All
select  2, 'c2', Null Union All
select  2, 'd2', Null Union All
select  2, 'e2', Null Union All
select  2, 'f2', Null Union All
select  2, 'g2', Null Union All
select  2, 'h2', Null 
--Select * from @tblFiltered
--Select * from @CompleteData
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 1 as ID,
       C.RowID,
       C.Position,
       F.Data
from tblComplete as C
  left outer join tblFiltered as F
    on C.Position = F.Position
order by C.RowID, C.Position
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets take the example where position is c1 in table tblComplete

You'll note that in your example there *is* no corresponding row in tblFiltered

so the tblFiltered.ID for the row with position c1 is in fact NULL

perhaps you'd like to do a case-statement on the ID
or only include rows where there is a match in tblFiltered?

Let us know which one and we can help you.

Comment: So do u want me to add some identity column by which I can keep track of .. please help

Comment: No this is up to you.  What is ID used for? obviously it's not a unique key (because your example has repeats). What do you want the ID to be if it exists in tblComplete but not in tblFiltered? do you want to use the ID that is in tblComplete instead? When you decide what you want the ID to be if it's not there in tblFiltered... then we can get working :)

Comment: Ok I got ur point.. We can look upon tblComplete as a lookup table which will have only the RowID, Column Positins(e.g. a1,b1...h8) . This is fixed. And the data will always be null. It cannot have a ID column. But tblFiltered can have repeated set of id's. So whatever I have given in the example is a set whose ID is 1. Likewise we can have more sets of values whose id's can be 2,3 etc. hope it makes sense.. Let me know if I have clear teh doubts

Comment: The question still remains though - if the item doesn't have an ID in tblFiltered - then do you even need the ID to be something other than NULL? AFAICS ID could only be used to go find the value in tblFiltered (which doesn't exist in this case)... so maybe NULL is ok.